# How to save files using devtools autosave while working on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, google-chrome-devtools, autosave

My website files are stored in c waamp www folder and i use devtools autosave to update my css file. But its not working while working on localhost. What do i need to do to make it work with localhost?

Comment: I want to know the answer to this too.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [this](http://12bubbles.com/2012/03/04/designers-tool-setting-up-chrome-dev-tools-autosave-on-windows/) will help you out

Comment: You should provide the solution here, not a link to a solution, because the linked page may vanish in the future, rendering this answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

since Google Dev Tools version 28 you will not need the extension "Autosave" anymore.

It has been substituted by Google Web Tools Workspace.

If you want to understand how to use Google workspace, you can ckeck-out this link:

[Live edit CSS and JS with Google dev tool](http://yoursoftengineer.blogspot.ie/2014/10/web-development-edit-your-css-and-html.html)

The only big limitation is that with google dev tools you can't edit DOM elements directly in the "elements" panel, neither the inline style definition.
However I found a better way for doing it;

There is an extension for Google Chrome that combined with an Intellij Idea plugin makes you live editing HTML, CSS, JS and it work amazingly.
It is probably better than using Google Dev Tool. The only disadvantage is that you cannot inspect the elements you are editing in the browser itself but you can obviously do it in your IDE which is even better.

I documented the process here if you want to take a look:

[Live edit CSS-HTML-JS with Intellij Idea](http://yoursoftengineer.blogspot.ie/2014/10/web-development-live-edit-your-html-css.html)

Luca

Comment: Instead of just linking to your documented process, can you provide it in with your answer?

Comment: Should I write it from scratch every time I want to help somebody ?

Comment: An answer on stackoverflow should be able to stand on its own to answer the question without someone having to follow external links. External links are welcome, but they tend to slowly break over time and thus should not be strictly required to get to the solution.

Comment: I understand your concers, but in this case the process is shown using images as well. Would be difficult without them.

Comment: You can embed images in an answer using the image button or by pressing `Ctrl+G`.